# CPack create package for pacman and MSYS2/ MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw, msys2, cpack

I already successfully created NSIS installers and Debian packages with CMake and CPack for other projects.

For a new C++ project I also want to provide various packages for different platforms. Besides Debian packages, I also want to create packages for MSYS2/ MinGW.

Now I am a little bit struggling to find documentation to create packages for MSYS2/ MinGW for pacman. Is this even possible and can CPack create packages for MSYS2/ MinGW?

Is there any documentation available or did somebody try the same? Can those packages create cross-platform? I know I can cross-compile for MinGW under Linux but can I also create those packages cross-platform?

Any hints would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "create packages cross-platform" exactly? You can cross-compile with MinGW, but you seem to mean something else.

Comment: Beside cross-compiling which is possible I also want to create the packages for pacman on a Linux machine. This is what I mean with create "packages cross-platform".

Comment: Have you tried using pacman on Linux (source code can be found at https://sources.archlinux.org/other/pacman/) ?